# How can I make redirect on page after login correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to redirect user after successful login. I did it this way but it does not work. How can I fix this issue or how can I do it correctly?

main.jsx

[image]

Login.jsx

```
imports ...

function Login() {
    const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [loginClass, setLoginClass] = useState('');
    const [passwordClass, setPasswordClass] = useState('');

    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    const submit = async (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log(login, password);
        if (login.length === 0 || password.length === 0) {
            console.log('stop')
            if (!login) { 
                setLoginClass('is-invalid'); 
            }

            if (!password) { 
                setPasswordClass('is-invalid');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('req')
            await axios
                .post('http://localhost:5000/test/auth/login', {
                    login: login,
                    password: password
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    const { data } = response;
                    if (data.status == 200) {
                        console.log('entered successfully');
                        setIsLoggedIn(true);
                    } else {
                        console.log('could not enter');
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });

            setPassword('');
            setLogin('');
            setLoginClass('');
            setPasswordClass('');
        }
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            return <Navigate to="/main" replace={true}/>
        }
        return
    };

    return (
        <div className="container col-xl-10 col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
            ...
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className={`form-control ${loginClass}`}
                                id="login"
                                placeholder="Login"
                                value={login}
                                onChange={(evt) => { setLogin(evt.target.value) }}
                            />
                            ...
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                className={`form-control ${passwordClass}`}
                                id="password"
                                placeholder="Password"
                                value={password}
                                onChange={(evt) => { setPassword(evt.target.value) }}
                            />
                        <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" onClick={submit}>Enter</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

- Attempting to return JSX from an asynchronous callback function.

  The code is attempting to issue a redirect from within the submit handler. You can't return JSX from a callback and expect it to be rendered to the DOM and have any effect. `Navigate` would need to be returned from the `Login` as part of the regular JSX it renders.
- Attempting to access a stale closure over state.

  `submit` enqueues some state updates and the code incorrectly attempts to access the `isLoggedIn` state to effect a redirect action.
- It is generally considered a Javascript anti-pattern to mix `async/await` with Promise chains. Pick one pattern or the other.

```js
const submit = async (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log(login, password);
  if (login.length === 0 || password.length === 0) {
    console.log('stop')
    if (!login) { 
      setLoginClass('is-invalid'); 
    }

    if (!password) { 
      setPasswordClass('is-invalid');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('req')
    await axios
      .post('http://localhost:5000/test/auth/login', {
        login: login,
        password: password
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const { data } = response;
        if (data.status == 200) {
          console.log('entered successfully');
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
          console.log('could not enter');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    setPassword('');
    setLogin('');
    setLoginClass('');
    setPasswordClass('');
  }

  if (isLoggedIn) { // <-- won't have value from any state enqueued updates above
    return <Navigate to="/main" replace={true} />; // <-- can't do this
  }
  return
};
```

## Solutions

1. Enqueue the `isLoggedIn` state update as you are and return the `Navigate` component with the regular JSX to issue a ***declarative*** redirect.

   ```
   function Login() {
     const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
     const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
     const [loginClass, setLoginClass] = useState('');
     const [passwordClass, setPasswordClass] = useState('');

     const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

     const submit = async (evt) => {
       evt.preventDefault();

       if (!login.length || !password.length) {
         if (!login) { 
           setLoginClass('is-invalid'); 
         }

         if (!password) { 
           setPasswordClass('is-invalid');
         }
       } else {
         try {
           const { data } = await axios.post(
             'http://localhost:5000/test/auth/login',
             { login, password }
           )

           if (data.status == 200) {
             setIsLoggedIn(true);
           } else {
             console.log('could not enter');
           }
         } catch(error) {
           console.log(error);
         };

         setPassword('');
         setLogin('');
         setLoginClass('');
         setPasswordClass('');
       }
     };

     // Return JSX from function component
     if (isLoggedIn) {
       return <Navigate to="/main" replace />; // <-- declarative redirect
     }

     return (
       ...
     );
   }
   ```
2. Use the `useNavigate` hook and issue an ***imperative*** redirect from the submit handler.

   ```
   import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
   ...

   function Login() {
     const navigate = useNavigate();

     const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
     const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
     const [loginClass, setLoginClass] = useState('');
     const [passwordClass, setPasswordClass] = useState('');

     const submit = async (evt) => {
       evt.preventDefault();

       if (!login.length || !password.length) {
         if (!login) { 
           setLoginClass('is-invalid'); 
         }

         if (!password) { 
           setPasswordClass('is-invalid');
         }
       } else {
         try {
           const { data } = await axios.post(
             'http://localhost:5000/test/auth/login',
             { login, password }
           )

           if (data.status == 200) {
             navigate("/main", { replace: true }); // <-- imperative redirect
           } else {
             console.log('could not enter');
           }
         } catch(error) {
           console.log(error);
         };

         setPassword('');
         setLogin('');
         setLoginClass('');
         setPasswordClass('');
       }
     };

     return (
       ...
     );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to achieve navigation in your React application is to use the `useNavigate` hook from `react-router-dom`

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

Modify this condition in your submit function

```
  if (data.status == 200) {
    console.log("entered successfully");
    navigate("/main");
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
  } else {
    console.log("could not enter");
  }
```